# Adding different kinds of tabs in Shiny Dashboard (after do.call)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to add a comparison tab(different structure) after creating a few view tabs(similar structure). This code throws an error of -

```
[1] "div"
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
```

Code -

```
Some_List <- list("IR", "FX", "EQ")
Some_Long_List <- list("Aggregated Things", "Component 1", "Component 2")
IO_List <- ("Some")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
do.call(sidebarMenu, list(c(lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(i) {
menuItem(Some_Long_List[i], tabName = paste0(Some_List[i],"_tab"))
})),menuItem("Comparison of Files", tabName="Comparison")))
)

uibody <- dashboardBody(
do.call(tabItems, c(lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(i) {
tabItem(tabName = paste0(Some_List[i],"_tab"), h2(Some_Long_List[i]),
fluidPage(fluidRow(column(3,
dateInput(paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[i]),label=h2("Select a Date"), value="2020-05-29")
,hr()
,actionButton(paste0("calculate_",Some_List[i]), paste0("Calculate ",Some_List[i]),class = "btn-md btn-primary" ))
,column(9,column(verbatimTextOutput(paste0("file_path_",Some_List[i])),width=12),hr(),
    selectInput(paste0('select_file_',Some_List[i]),'Select a File to display', choices=NULL),hr(),
    column(dataTableOutput(paste0('selected_table_',Some_List[i])),width=12)))))
}))
,tabItem(tabName = "Comparison", h2("Data Comparison"),fluidPage(fluidRow(column(3,
        fileInput('Dat1', 'Choose First Data:', accept = c(".csv", ".txt")),
        fileInput('Dat2', 'Choose Second Data:', accept = c(".csv", ".txt")))
    ,column(9,tableOutput('Comparison_Results'))))))
)
)
```

Any help on how to add a tab after do.call? Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you want:

```
Some_List <- c("IR", "FX", "EQ")
Some_Long_List <- c("Aggregated Things", "Component 1", "Component 2")

do.call(
  tabItems, 
  c(
    lapply(
      1:length(Some_List), 
      function(i) {
        tabItem(
          tabName = paste0(Some_List[i],"_tab"), 
          h2(Some_Long_List[i]),
          fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
              column(
                3,
                dateInput(paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[i]),label=h2("Select a Date"), value="2020-05-29")
                ,hr()
                ,actionButton(paste0("calculate_",Some_List[i]), paste0("Calculate ",Some_List[i]),class = "btn-md btn-primary" )
              )
              ,column(
                9,
                column(verbatimTextOutput(paste0("file_path_",Some_List[i])),width=12),
                hr(),
                selectInput(paste0('select_file_',Some_List[i]),'Select a File to display', choices=NULL),
                hr(),
                column(dataTableOutput(paste0('selected_table_',Some_List[i])),width=12)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      }
    ),
    list(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Comparison", 
        h2("Data Comparison"),
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(
              3,
              fileInput('Dat1', 'Choose First Data:', accept = c(".csv", ".txt")),
              fileInput('Dat2', 'Choose Second Data:', accept = c(".csv", ".txt"))
            ),
            column(
              9,
              tableOutput('Comparison_Results')
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried that as well, error -  ``[1] "div"
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.``

Comment: That's great, thank you very much. Of all the combinations I tried, it never occurred to me that I can take ``tabItems`` out. Many thanks.